# get sum of the same element from the list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to get sum from the list using generics as like

```
List<Name,Value> test=new List<Name,Value>();
E.g list contain these element
test.Add(One,5);
test.Add(Second,5);
test.Add(Third,5);
test.Add(One,5);
test.Add(One,5);
test.Add(Second,5);
```

At the end want to get value as like
Element with One name contain value 15
Element with Second name contain value 10
Element with Third name contain value 5

I don't want to iterate each element manually.
This is not an exact syntax, it an idea.

Comment: List<Name,Value> is not a valid declaration. List<T> is a single type parameter collection, it supports single classes.

Comment: I'm using generics to do as i mentioned in my question. it contain one object but that object have two element first is name and second one is value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do you need something like this

```
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> test = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("One",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Second",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Third",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("One",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("One",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Second",5));

var result = test.GroupBy(r => r.Key).Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(r.Key, r.Sum(p => p.Value))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> test = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("One",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Second",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Third",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("One",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("One",5));
test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Second",5));

var sum = test.Where( x => x.Key == "One" ).Sum( y => y.Value );
```